# How to prevent from being denied access to execute commands for remote computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am using the Stop-Computer Powershell cmdlet on my VM for remote control practice but everytime i try to use the command it gives me an access is denied error. One of the solutions i found on the internet was to disable the firewall as that may be preventing access but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions? or ideas why i am getting this error.

My code

Stop-Computer 172.31.146.121 -Credential DESKTOP-8NP58DR\SulekhaOmar

The error:

Stop-Computer : Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1

- Stop-Computer 172.31.146.121 -Credential DESKTOP-8NP58DR\SulekhaOmar
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-Computer], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopComputerCommand
  ```

Comment: If you are an Admin on network you do no need credentials. Make sure you start Powershell by right click and select Run As Admin.

Comment: On the Microsoft Website where i got this cmdlet, i have to include credentials if i want to  remotely shut down a machine. However, if it is local, i don't need the credentials @jdweng

Comment: You only need credentials if you do not have the credentials on the remote machine.  Most networks block credentials unless they are encrypted.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: so if the vm has it's own admin credentials the code above wouldn't work? and Also, i have removed the credentials aspect, and i still get the same error? do you have any suggestions why? @jdweng

Comment: You need to be an admin on both local and remote machines.  The Group Policy would give you the authorization.

Comment: So i need to add the vm to the list of group policies from my host computer? @jdweng

Comment: I don't know your network.  Usually corporate networks have higher level admin controlling accessing between machines.  If you can change the Group Policy for network than make sure the account allows admin on both local and remote machines.

Comment: Did you start the PowerShell console using `Run as Administrator`?